# Suppress the Attachment dialog in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

So I have a double click event on an OLE object to send an email and after that executes the attachment dialog comes up.  I have the field locked so the user cannot update the picture anyway but I would prefer it not show at all.  Is there anyway to suppress this dialog?

[image: Dialog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm assuming here you're using an attachment field and not an OLE object field)

You can cancel showing the attachment dialog, by setting Cancel = True in the `DoubleClick` event, like this:

```
Private Sub myAttachmentField_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it.  You were right, it is an attachment field in the table that I'm referencing.  Is there also a way to hide the paperclip for that field?

Comment: Not off the top of my head (except for disabling the field which you probably don't want to do), but that's a valid second question. Perhaps you should ask it here, so other people can answer it and find it more easily.